# PHP can't exec an C++ script with OpenCV

Tags: php, c++, apache, opencv

I've got a problem - I have writen simple app in C++ that's use OpenCV library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int faceDetect(string filename);

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    int result = 0;
    string filename(argv[1]);

    Mat image = imread("C:/Serwer/Apache24/htdocs/image/upload/" + filename, 1);

        if (image.empty()) {
            return 101;
        }
        CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
        if( !faceCascade.load("C:/Serwer/Apache24/htdocs/image/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml") ){
             return 103;
         };

        Mat imageGray;
        std::vector<Rect> faces;

        cvtColor(image, imageGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(imageGray, imageGray);

        feCascade.detectMultiScale(imageGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            Rect face(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
            rectangle(image, face, Scalar(195, 144, 212));
            Mat faceROI = imageGray(faces[i]);
        }

        imwrite("C:/Serwer/Apache24/htdocs/image/result/" + filename, image);
        return 1;

    return result;
}
```

When I run the script with cmd everything is ok - the result file is created.

I would like to use this script in my web app (php + js + html), but when i try to run it like this:

```
<?php
 $output = [];
 $return = 0;
 exec("test.exe lenna.png", $output, $return);
 echo "return: " . $return . "<br>";
 print_r($output);
?>
```

The file is not created, $return is 255 and $output is an empty array. I e tried to add "2 &>1" in the exec command but then file is still not created (but $return is 1). I've also tried other php functions (system() and shell_exec()) but it still didn't create a result file.

The exe is in the same directory as php script (I've tried to run it with absolute path - stil same problem). result catalouge exists. There is no disabled functions in php.ini, in path variable I can see OpenCV's libs path. When i run this code:

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
 system("dir");
 echo "</pre>";
?>
```

it works.

OS: Win 8.1 x64
Apache 2.4.6 x64 (apachelounge version)
PHP 5.6.13 x64 (fcgi_mod)

Any ideas what should i do?

---

**EDIT**
I've identified the problem - when I run PHP as mod_fcgid my cpp doesn't work. When I run php as apache module (php5apache2_4.dll) everything works fine.

I've got my current mod_fcgid configuration from here: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=2394

And it looks like this:

```
<IfModule fcgid_module> 
   FcgidIOTimeout 40 
   FcgidConnectTimeout 10 

   FcgidMaxProcesses 300 
   FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 300 

   FcgidOutputBufferSize 64 
   ProcessLifeTime 0 
   FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0 
   FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0 
   FcgidFixPathinfo 0 
   FcgidProcessLifeTime 0 
   FcgidZombieScanInterval 20 
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 536870912 
   FcgidIOTimeout 120 
   FcgidTimeScore 3 

   FcgidPassHeader Authorization 

   FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:\\Serwer\\PHP5" 
   FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:\\Serwer\\PHP5;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:\\Windows" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:\\WINDOWS" 
   <Files ~ "\.php$"> 
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
      FcgidWrapper "C:/Serwer/PHP5/php-cgi.exe" .php 
   </Files> 
</IfModule>
```

There is no errors in Apache's error.log. Do you know what should I change in fcgid configuration to exec external cpp application?

Comment: Check the error log. Test with a different program that doesn't have any dependencies. Make sure you have necessary permissions. Also, test outside of Apache, you can run PHP programs standalone.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question - the problem is with Apache's mod_fcgid configuration. As temporary solution I've change configuration to run PHP as APache's module.